# need to find file source

Tags: html, css

I'm new to `html` and `css`. I have downloaded an html template online and I want to change the color of a text but can't find the class for the code in the files.

I've tried to inspect the website and look for the folder to change the color of text but I couldn't find it.

[image: Click to view image]

```
<div class="col-6 col-xl-2">
  <h1 class="mb-0 site-logo"><a href="index.html" class="text-black h2 mb- 
      0">lorem<span class="text-primary">.</span> </a></h1>
</div>
```

The class that i want to find is "text-primary" and change the color of the dot next to the "lorem" text.

Help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

[image: Click to view the image]

Comment: The image shows it as coming from **`_text-emphasis.scss`**, line 7 (see pane on the right side).

Comment: Do you want to change Lorem color?

Comment: Oh your template that you downloaded uses https://sass-lang.com/ as css preprocessor.. so you need to change it in text-emphasis.scss but if you are new to html that can be hard for you to setup SASS... change that class from text-primary to anything you want and then write the css anywhere you like....

Comment: @TareefImanAziziAhmadZakir yes but it is a file used by a program that generates styles... so you should find a easier template.... with pure CSS like... Older template..  or here i see some answers so look on what people are advising

Answer (score 1):

You can find the class in text-emphasis.scss file at line 7, or you can change the styles of the class using internal css.

```
<style>
.text-primary{
color:red !important; 
}
</style>
```

*The !important property in CSS is used to provide more weight (importance) than normal property. In CSS, the !important means that “this is important”, ignore all the subsequent rules, and apply !important rule and the !important keyword must be placed at the end of the line, immediately before the semicolon.*

Answer (score 0):

look for the highlighted file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS.

```
.text-black .text-primary { color:#000 !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .text-black {
            color: #000000!important;
            text-decoration: none!important;
        }
        .text-black .text-primary {
            color: #46ddb0!important;
        }
        .text-black-two {
            color: #000000!important;
            text-decoration: none!important;
        }
        .text-black-two .text-primary-two {
            color: #000000!important;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="col-6 col-xl-2">
        <h1 class="mb-0 site-logo">
            <a href="index.html" class="text-black h2 mb-0">lorem<span class="text-primary">.</span></a>
        </h1>
    </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-xl-2">
        <h1 class="mb-0 site-logo">
            <a href="index.html" class="text-black-two h2 mb-0">lorem<span class="text-primary-two">.</span></a>
        </h1>
    </div>
```